# wxPython StaticText widget "flickering"

Tags: python, wxpython, clock

I'm trying to make a digital clock. One of the problems with it is that the display will "flicker". In other words the **wx.StaticText** widget (**self.ST** in this case), will go blank for very short periods. I believe the cause may find it's root in how **self.ST** updates (ie, **SetLabel()**). Is there a way to provide smoother transitions, in an effort to stop the flickering?

This is the function where **self.ST** is updated:

```
def tick (self):
    ''' Continually updates the time. '''

    TimeStr = '%I:%M %S %p'
    DateStr = '%A, %B %d, %Y'


    Time = time.strftime(TimeStr)
    Date = time.strftime(DateStr)

    self.TimeDate =  Time + '\t\t' + Date

    self.ST.SetLabel(Time)

    wx.CallLater(1000, self.tick)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that it takes more than one monitor refresh to update the text or it happens in just the inappropriate time in regards to the [hsync](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/h/hsync.htm).

As it is, `StaticText` does not give you the low level control necessary to deal with this.

What you can do is use a [`BufferedDC`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.BufferedDC-class.html) and [`DrawText`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.DC-class.html#DrawText), or maybe take a look at [`LEDNumberCtrl`](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216962).

Comment: **Incorrect**. As @Oleksiy's answer describes, you just have to call `.SetDoubleBuffered(True)` on the parent-object of the `StaticText`.

Answer (score 9):

One way to fix the flickering is to enable double buffering in the top container for your widget. Normally this is done by calling `self.SetDoubleBuffered(True)` within the initialiser, for example within `Panel` container for your `StaticText` class.

Comment: This fixes the issue. The other answer (doing your own drawing) is gross overkill for the problem. You can also call `SetDoubleBuffered` directly on the panel, rather then having to override the initializer, e.g. `self.statusReadoutPanel.SetDoubleBuffered(True)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use wx.Timer instead
Please check wxpython demo and [wx.Timer-class](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Timer-class.html)