# wx.StaticText updates slower with whitespace?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm writing a simple [roguelike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roguelike) in Python 3.10 as a way to learn the language as well as principles of proper software architecture. I'm using wxPython310 (4.1.2a2).

The map is an octagonal grid of cells that player may traverse. My map is a `wx.StaticText` that updates once every user input. I set it to `DoubleBuffered`, as per advice I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294274/wxpython-statictext-widget-flickering). It works really nice.

Recently I started implementing field of vision mechanics that makes tiles (grid cells) outside of player's nearby surroundings return 'fog of war' character and only display their actual character representation once a player approaches (the player is denoted as '@' character):

[image: The player is @ character.]

**I noticed that if I keep holding a move arrow, the `wx.StaticText` doesn't update until I release it**. Disabling `DoubleBuffered` obviously corrects that behaviour, but makes the screen very blinky (as in, it flickers very rapidly). What's more interesting, **I noticed that the `wx.StaticText` updates correctly and quickly if a 'fog of war' character is some actual character, rather than just whitespace** (in the following example, an underscore):

[image]

**It's as if `wxStaticText` updated slower when there's plenty of whitespace, but quicker if there's a proper character.**

My reproducible example code:

```
import wx


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Title = 'Stackoverflow example'
        self.SetSize(width=1480, height=600)

        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel,1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Center()
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.mymap = MyMap()
        self.x = -1
        self.moveRight = True

        self.SetDoubleBuffered(True)

        font = wx.Font(9, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.DEFAULT)
        font.SetFaceName('Courier New')
        self.ST = wx.StaticText(self, label=self.Display(), style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
        self.ST.SetFont(font)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.EvaluateCommand)

    def EvaluateCommand(self,e):
        key = e.GetKeyCode()
        if key == 78: # n for newbie!
            self.MoveRectangleOnAMap()
            self.ST.SetLabel(self.Display())
        elif key == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:
            quit()

    def MoveRectangleOnAMap(self):
        all_tiles = self.mymap.FindRectangleOfTiles((0, 0), (self.mymap.width, self.mymap.height))
        for tile in all_tiles:
            tile.SetDisplayToDormant()

        if self.moveRight:
            self.x += 1
            if self.x == self.mymap.width - 15:
                self.moveRight = False
        else:
            self.x -= 1
            if self.x == 0:
                self.moveRight = True

        rectangle = self.mymap.FindRectangleOfTiles((self.x, 10), (self.x + 15, 25))
        for tile in rectangle:
            tile.SetDisplayToActive()

    def Display(self):
        width = self.mymap.width
        height = self.mymap.height
        text = ''

        for y in range(0,height):
            line = ''
            for x in range(0,width):
                line += self.mymap.FindTileFromCoords((x,y)).display
            text += line + '\n'

        return text


class Tile():
    def __init__(self,coords):
        self.coords = coords
        self.SetDisplayToDormant()

    def SetDisplayToActive(self):
        self.display = ' '

    def SetDisplayToDormant(self):
        self.display = '#'


class MyMap():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tiles = dict()
        self.width = 200
        self.height = 35

        for x in range(0,self.width):
            self.tiles[str(x)] = dict()
            for y in range(0,self.height):
                self.tiles[str(x)][str(y)]= Tile((x,y))

    def FindTileFromCoords(self,coords):
        coord_x, coord_y = coords
        return self.tiles[str(coord_x)][str(coord_y)]

    def FindRectangleOfTiles(self,coords_up_left, coords_down_right):
        coords_up_left_x, coords_up_left_y = coords_up_left
        coords_down_right_x, coords_down_right_y = coords_down_right
        tiles = []

        for x in range(coords_up_left_x,coords_down_right_x):
            for y in range(coords_up_left_y,coords_down_right_y):
                tiles.append(self.FindTileFromCoords((x,y)))

        return tiles


app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame()
app.MainLoop()
```

If I execute this code and press and hold 'n' on keyboard (n for newbie!), the rectangle moves in nice and steady fashion. If you switch around the characters in `Tile` class...:

```
class Tile():
    def __init__(self,coords):
        self.coords = coords
        self.SetDisplayToDormant()

    def SetDisplayToActive(self):
        self.display = '#'

    def SetDisplayToDormant(self):
        self.display = ' '
```

... and hold 'n' again, the `StaticText` label won't update until you release the key.

Could someone explain to me why that is? And is there some smart way to circumvent that problem?

Comment: we can't see your code and we can't run it to check if we also have this problem. Maybe it is problem only on your computer.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (see this [code of a wxPython application](https://pastebin.com/pn86mFiK))

Comment: Thanks for the replies, guys! I edited the original post to include the example.

Comment: Performing a `self.Update()` will resolve the update/release key issue. i.e. force the widget to refresh itself, after each key depression. You could try defining the rectangle to update with `Refresh(rect=myrectangle)` but it's a diminishing return sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Switch whitespace to no-break whitespace.**

As [VZ.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15275/vz) mentioned, `wxStaticText` aren't really meant to be used to update big blobs of text. However, he also mentioned that the word wrapping in `wxStaticText` is a probable culprit for this stuttery behaviour. This got me thinking, if that's word wrapping that's causing it, how may I circumvent it? Well, it turns out that switching a standard whitespace character (`U+0020`) to a no-break space (`U+00A0`) indeed makes the widget updates much more smooth! In my reproducible code example, it's especially trivial, since Python 3+ makes all strings utf-8 encoded:

```
class Tile():
    def __init__(self,coords):
        self.coords = coords
        self.SetDisplayToDormant()

    def SetDisplayToActive(self):
        self.display = '#'

    def SetDisplayToDormant(self):
        self.display = '\u00a0'
```

**2. Use `GenStaticText` instead.**

It turns out using `wx.lib.stattext.GenStaticText` instead of `wxStaticText` also seems to correct the issue and is probably also way more sensible.

Answer (score 0):

`wxStaticText` is really not meant to be used for efficiently updating large blobs of text. You need to implement your own window that would redraw just the parts of it that really need to be changed.

Comment: I understand that. At this point I'm interested what makes my two cases behave differently. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Probably word wrapping in `wxStaticText`. But it's really not a very interesting question, you're using a control in a way it's not supposed to be used at all, so it's not really important to know why exactly it doesn't work for you -- when it was never the appropriate choice in the first place.

Comment: I acknowledge you're right and I understand your point. This is just a pet project, which coincidentally is also the first time I use any kind of Python GUI -- so more of a learning experience than anything else. I would also thank you very much for taking your time in reviewing my question and sharing your suggestion that a word wrapping is a culprit. It helped me stumble upon a solution to my problem, which was replacing standard whitespace (`U+0020`) with a no-break space (`U+00A0`). I understand I'm kinda missing the point you were trying to make, but hey, I'm just glad it works!